# Read Text file and use call stored procedure to insert the data

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

I need to read a data file that's comma-separated:

```
a,123,C:/test.txt,0001
```

I need to read them the line into array then use a call method to call a stored procedure.
This will then data from text file and then put into columns in the table.

I have this so far:

```vb
Dim path As String
path = "C:\Users\dave\Desktop\WF.txt"

Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(path)

Dim line As String
line = ""

' Split(
Do
  Try
    line = sr.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine(line)
  Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine("the file could not be read:")
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
  End Try
Loop Until line Is Nothing

sr.Close()
```

Comment: And **which** database is this for?? Calling a stored procedure is highly specific to what database system you're using.

Comment: I have my text file like shown above I need to insert this data from text file to sql server database 05,there has an insert stored procedure created.Each data after comma will into different field using the store procedure in vb.net.

Comment: I need to pass the arrays from text file to stored procedure using vb.net.
data is comma separated on text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
Dim path As String = "C:\Users\dave\Desktop\WF.txt"
Dim line As String = String.Empty

' define connection string and stored procedure name 
Dim connectionString As String = "server=.;database=test;integrated Security=SSPI;"
Dim storedProcedureName As String = "dbo.YourInsertStoredProcedure"

' put all disposable items in using() blocks - this applies to 
' StreamReader, SqlConnection, SqlCommand (and many more!)
Using sr As New StreamReader(path)
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, conn)
            ' define as stored procedure
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            ' define parameters
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param2", SqlDbType.Int)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 260)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param4", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25)

            Do
                Try
                    line = sr.ReadLine()

                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) Then
                        ' split line into the four parts
                        Dim parts As String() = line.Split(",")

                        ' set the parameter values
                        cmd.Parameters("@Param1").Value = parts(0)
                        cmd.Parameters("@Param2").Value = Convert.ToInt32(parts(1))
                        cmd.Parameters("@Param3").Value = parts(2)
                        cmd.Parameters("@Param4").Value = parts(3)

                        ' execute procedure
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Console.WriteLine("the file could not be read:")
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                End Try
            Loop While Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks Marc that's very close of what im trying to do ...
GOd bless

Comment: What if I had to do the same thing but my reader is reading row by row in a specific column and then use the same store procedure

Comment: What if I had to do the same thing but my reader is reading row by row in a specific column and then use the same store procedure